# Parsing through HTML Page

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have the task of parsing through a HTML Page to retrieve the username of the person accessing the page. The username will be listed on the HTML Page, but may be located in different locations for different people. I wanted to get an idea of how other people will solve this problem.

I was planning on using JSoup to parse through the HTML Page and use keywords to find where the name is located, however this may not work as each page for each person is different so the same keyword can be in different places.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do - why would the user name be in different places in different files? If they are pages from different sites, say, you might need a rule set for where to search. Or would you want to detect me typing Amav Malviya in a random comment?

Comment: Different users maybe using different templates of this website. Each template shows the username in a different place, so how would I find the username in each of these templates.

Comment: If you control the templates, perhaps add a named `span`: `<span id="here-be-username">Amav Malviya</span>`?

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon Arnav,

A while back I had a client asking me to write a system to parse (very poorly written) html files in Java. Due to the lack of consistency, I had to build class to go through the file and manually look for keywords/HTML tags.

Personally, I would go with JSoup to do the parsing. Please see below for an example of my code.

```
    // Get all data from HTML file =============================
    public Object[] parseTag(String tag) {                  // =
        Document doc;                                       // =
        try {                                               // =
            File input = new File(this.Path);               // =
            doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");          // =
            Elements pTag = doc.getElementsByTag(tag);      // =
            Object[] pTagA = pTag.toArray();                // =
            return pTagA;                                   // =
        } catch (IOException e) {                           // =
            e.printStackTrace();                            // =
            return null;                                    // =
        }                                                   // =
    }                                                       // =
    // =========================================================
```

You can call this function and pass it an html tag and it will return an array of objects for every instance of that tag in the file/page. Example: parseTag("a"); will return all of the links on the page.

**Example:**

I wanted to get the account number from the html file. After running a couple of tests, I discovered the account number is inside of a  tag, and is the 6th instance of it.

```
    // Get Account Number ==================================================
    public String getAccountNumber() {                                  // =
        Object[] bTag = this.parseTag("font");                          // =
        String data = bTag[5].toString();                               // =
        data = data.replace("<font size=\"4\" color=\"white\">", "");   // =
        data = data.split("<br>")[0];                                   // =
        this.AccountNumber = data;                                      // =
        return data;                                                    // =
    }                                                                   // =
    // =====================================================================
```

I called the function and stripped out the additional information until I got the data.

You can do a little research on JSoup and play around with it until it fits your needs, but this is what I did in the past to get similar results.

Thanks,
Tim